# Emotion doesn't have effect on material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to use emotion in my code but it seems it has no effect on it. And there is no error message.

And I also tried the `sx` , it works.

Anything I missed?

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";

import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Container,
  IconButton,
  Box,
  Tooltip,
  Icon,
  Avatar,
} from "@mui/material";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ViewHeadline";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <Box
            css={css`
              margin-left: auto;
            `}
          >
            <Tooltip title="Open Peronal Setting">
              <IconButton>
                <Avatar>c</Avatar>
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the elements you want to change  and specify the css properties in the right way.

Look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-framework-mzbxt2?file=/demo.tsx) the way the `margin-right` is added for the icon instead of the way you have it.

Here is the working code

```
return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{
              "&.MuiIconButton-root": {
                marginRight: 2
              }
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <Box>
            <Tooltip title="Open Peronal Setting">
              <IconButton>
                <Avatar>c</Avatar>
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
```